# Histogram with Known Density using ggplot2 - R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a vector of data with random variable values and another vector with the respective probabilities.
Is there a known function which cleverly draws the histogram or approximate density function?
Doing simple line plots is not always very informative due to outlier data and/or a concentration of points around some value.
Thanks.

EDIT: I would like to use ggplot2.

Comment: plot( density(x) )

Comment: What is x? A vector? A dataframe?

Comment: a vector with your data

Comment: I am sorry, I mean using ggplot. My mistake, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example how you could use `ggplot2` to make a histogram, density or both.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_histogram()

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_density(colour = '#BD1515', fill = '#BD1515', alpha = 0.2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = ..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = '#CF3030') + 
  geom_density(colour = '#BD1515', fill = '#BD1515', alpha = 0.35)
```

Comment: If you don't know ggplot2 you may want to try this [app](http://michalm.net/shiny/easyPlot/) out.

Comment: To get what the OP wants you need to use the weight argument within the aes statement with the probabilities as the weights.

Comment: Exactly Andy, I want to provide the densities/probabilities (since its discrete...) values myself.